# Don't force me to provide a month

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

I don't want to include specific months on my developer story items (only years).

The old CV allowed you to save items without months, and the story format clearly works with monthless items (since my migrated items have no months).  I'm now unable to edit migrated items without adding a month.

Comment: Yes please. This is immensely useful for old projects where I know the years but have no remote idea what months they started and stopped in. I get that this makes it impossible to calculate an actual length, but that can easily just be ommitted if a month is not provided at either point, if necessary.

Comment: I agree, I was going to create my story and saw that months were required and thought maybe I will do it later. Grant it, I was not in the most ambitious mood. I can imagine, many others have done the same. Let the months be optional and remind the author afterwards by notification.

Comment: I wish every site had at least remote chance of starting a forum post about annoying limiting feature and actually having a hope that it really will be fixed and knowing that the developers kinda care...

Comment: @animuson You can still calculate a length with an error of +/-1 year. For example 2001-20011 would have length (10 years +/- 1 year). If you specify months too, the error is +/-1 month instead. If you have to provide months but don't know them anymore, use 01 or 06 as convention, I would say.

Comment: @Trilarion - you've made an off-by-18000 years error in your calculation. :-)

Comment: Huh? I managed to add new items without giving a month. Just leave the box empty.

Comment: @OrangeDog I had too when developer story was first released, but the boxes have since changed from a single input box to a dropdown for the month and an input box for the year, and it no longer saves without both being entered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been fixed. We recently changed date controls from a single text input to a dropdown for the month and an input for the year, and forgot to make sure the new format still allowed year-only dates to be informed. I removed the validation check on the month dropdown, so you should be able to inform only years again.

Comment: Thanks!  Working as expected now.